# jQuery unwrap ul li texts to single line text with commas and quotes

Tags: jquery

How can I unwrap all these to single line text with commas and quotes? Also adding new text "category" for each first li title, so the result will be this: `"category","Title_A","Title_A1","Title_A2","category","Title_B","Title_B1","Title_B2"`

```
<div class="category">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Title_A
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Title_A1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Title_A2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Title_B
            <ul>
            <li>
                Title_B1
            </li>
            <li>
                Title_B2
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. There was a bug. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty method:

```js
$(function () {
  mainArray = [];
  $(".category > ul > li").each(function () {
    mainArray.push("category");
    mainArray = mainArray.join(",");
    mainArray += ","+($(this).text().trim().split(" ").join(","));
    mainArray = mainArray.split(",");
  });
  mainArray = mainArray.filter(function (n) {
    return (n != undefined && n.trim().length != 0);
  }).map(function (n) {
    return n.trim();
  });
  alert(mainArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Title_A
      <ul>
        <li>
          Title_A1
        </li>
        <li>
          Title_A2
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Title_B
      <ul>
        <li>
          Title_B1
        </li>
        <li>
          Title_B2
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```